# Adding wxWidgets to a project using cmake in Windows

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, wxwidgets

I am trying to add wxWidgets to my project using cmake.

in cmake I have:

```
#wxWidgets
set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION mswu)
find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base REQUIRED)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
```

and for my project in cmake I have:

```
target_link_libraries(MyProject
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

and then  run cmake using:

```
 cmake -G  "Visual Studio 11 Win64" ..
```

but when I compile the generated project in visual studio I am getting link error:

```
 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl wxSplashScreen::wxSplashScreen(class wxBitmap const &,long,int,class wxWindow *,int,class wxPoint const &,class wxSize const &,long)" (??0wxSplashScreen@@QEAA@AEBVwxBitmap@@JHPEAVwxWindow@@HAEBVwxPoint@@AEBVwxSize@@J@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(void)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@XZ) 

 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl wxSplashScreen::~wxSplashScreen(void)" (??1wxSplashScreen@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(void)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@XZ) 

 unresolved external symbol main referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

wxSplashScreen is part of the [wxAdvanced library](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/page_libs.html#page_libs_wxadv), so you need to tell cmake to link to that as well as core and base:

```
find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base adv REQUIRED)
```